# Несколько форм в один ряд

Tags: css

Подскажите, как поставить формы так, чтобы в каждом ряду было по 4 формы, а потом переход на следующий ряд ?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот как оно щас выглядит.

Comment: Какие формы? Вот те голубые кнопки? Они у вас как `<form>` сделаны?

Comment: Да, эти голубые кнопки.

Answer (score 1):

Так (не забыв убрать лишние пробельные символы из разметки):

```
width: 25%;
display: inline-block;
```

Ну или так:

```
width: 25%;
float: left;
```

Или flexbox.

Comment: Оно то получилось, но теперь на форму нельзя нажать.

Comment: @Андрей Inspect element и разбирайся. По идее, такого не должно быть.